# FFmpeg streaming rtmp muliple streams

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I have a mpeg file with two video streams stream
`#0:0[0x27] yuv420p 352X288` 
and
`#0:1[0x29] yuv420p 640X480`

I am trying to read the file and send it out rtmp

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i myvideofile.mpg -f mpegts udp://localhost:123456`

To verify the stream is streaming I use ffplay

`ffplay udp://localhost:123456`

I get the video, but it is only one of the two streams I am expecting. the 640x480

Is there something that I need to do to make both streams get sent?

Comment: Have you tried pressing "v" key while playing? That should cycle through video streams per [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html#While-playing)

Comment: yes both v and c. and when i run ffmpeg -i on the stream it only shows the one video
ffmpeg -i on the original file shows both

Answer (score 0):

To remap all streams you have to pass -map 0.

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i myvideofile.mpg -map 0 -f mpegts udp://localhost:123456`